# Setting a session variable for use in Symfony controller PHPUnit tests with redirects

Tags: php, symfony, session, phpunit, functional-testing

I'm trying to create a functional test that involves persisting a session variable across redirects. The logging in part seems to work but I can't set and keep a session variable.

The test class extends WebTestCase.

```
$this->client = static::createClient();
$this->client->followRedirects();
```

authenticating

```
$user = $em->getRepository('MyApp\AppBundle\Entity\User')
        ->findOneByUsername('gagarin');
$firewall = 'secured_area';
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(),
        $firewall, $user->getRoles());
self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
$session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');
$session->set('_security_' . $firewall, serialize($token));
// tried $session->set('color_id', 1234) here
$session->save();
$cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
$this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
```

the '/' route will redirect to a login page and then back to the '/' page 
    because followRedirects is set to true.

```
$crawler = $this->client->request(
        'GET',
        'http://myapp.test/');
$this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
```

What I'd like to do is set a session variable (`color_id`) which I can assert exists on the requested route, following redirects to login or other pages that '/' routes to based on color_id. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've put my authentication in an own class AbstractControllerTest.
Here is the relevant code for session handling:

```
abstract class AbstractControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    protected $session = [];

    public function addSession($session): void
    {
        $this->session = array_merge($this->session, $session);
    }

    protected function createAuthorizedClient()
    {
        //Here comes your client logic...

        foreach ($this->session as $sessionKey => $sessionValue) {
            $session->set($sessionKey, $sessionValue);
        }

        $container->get('session')->save();
        $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));

        return $client;
    }
}
```

In your Test use AbstractControllerTest and set additional Session Variables in your setUp() Method like this:

```
class MyTest extends AbstractControllerTest
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->addSession(['variable' => 'value']);

        parent::setUp();
    }
}
```